# Check information from another array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables in the database, the table circle and the table gossips.
The table circle has 3 columns: id, idfrom, idto.
The table gossips has id, userid, gossip.
My objectif is to echo all the gossips only if the userid of this gossip (idto) and the id of the pageuser(idfrom) are on the same row in the table circle.
I wrote this code,

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM gossips ORDER BY id DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query)
    or die("Couldn't execute query");
$querycircle = 'SELECT idfrom,idto FROM circle WHERE idfrom="{$pageuserid}" ';
$resultcircle = mysqli_query($cxn, $querycircle)
    or die("Couldn't check if user in circle.");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    while($rowcheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcircle))
    {
        if($row['userid'] == $rowcheck['idto'] || $row['userid'] == $_COOKIE['id']){
             echo '<div class="gossip">'.$row['gossip'].'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the single SQL query for this and then try with one while loop.

```
Select A.gossip from gossips A, circle B where A.userid=B.idto and B.idfrom="{$pageuserid}" order by A.id DESC;
```

NOTE: you can also compare the COOKIE value by adding the extra comparison on the query, like `and B.userid=$_COOKIE["id"]` (better to save the cookie value in a variable)

Comment: Why did you only select A.gossip and you didn't select userid

Comment: It is not needed for the example to work. ;) If you also need the userid in your program, you can expand the query to: `Select A.gossip, A.userid from gossips A, circle B ......`

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to get the same data with `mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcircle))` on each round of the first while-loop?

Then you should buffer this data in an array first, as executing `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will always give you the next data set on each successive call. It will not restart on top of the data.

(Btw, this is better: `while(null !== ($rowcheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))`)

---

Another method to realize your objective is to do only one combined SQL request.

EDIT: Sudip Pal is fast, look at his answer for a combined request! ;)

Comment: How can I make it restart then ?

Comment: I do not recommend it, but you can do it with the function [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php). It would be better to cache the mysql result in a php-array.